# One of the two copies of the Rusty Sword can be safely sold without losing the chance for anything?

Tags: lost-ruins

Looking at a guide online, there doesn't seem to be a real weapon-upgrade mechanic, so selling duplicate copies of anything that's not one of the few quest requirements (Elemental Runes, Hammer, etc) won't lead me to lose out on anything, right?

There's no point to trying to put two copies of the same weapon in both of the handheld-equipment slots?

Answer (score 1):

There is no upgrade system, and I have no recollection of the rusty sword being used for anything special. If the guide also doesn't mention anything, it's safe to sell it.

I don't believe it is even possible to equip two of the same weapon. I just tried and it shows up in the inventory as "Weapon (2)", just like with throwable weapons. Since there's only one entry, I can't equip it in both arms slots.